# suppress some warnings in cron job

Tags: cron, warnings, suppress

I am running a backup script as a cron job. I am getting the error: Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.

I am aware of how my scripts are set up and I am not in a shared environment, so this is not a warning I want to continually get. I tried the following command (found elsewhere on stack overflow), but it does not work.

```
45  5   *   *   *   /home/username/scripts/automysqlbackup-2.5.1-01.sh 2>&1 | grep -v 'Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.'
```

The problem is that I am still getting the warning and it seems that all warnings are changed to this text. Can someone give me the proper syntax? I searched Google for a long time and this doesn't seem to be a common question.

Thank you!